# Image in email attachment is not saving to the Photos app

Tags: email, photos, attachments

I'm trying to save some images from an email attachment in the Mail app. There are five images, but for some reason, only three have been saved in the Photos app. I have tried long-pressing the images and tapping "Save Image" and "Save 5 Images". All five images are jpg files. Nothing so far has worked. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: For me, the saved images weren't showing up in my "Library" tab in the Photos app, but they appeared in my "Albums" tab under the "Recents" album. So dumb. Edit: this is on iPhone that I'm speaking on. I just realized I'm on a Mac forum, but maybe it also applies

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it's the same story as saving a screenshot or any other photo from online etc.

Pictures like that are not automatically added to the Photos app, you have to import them yourself.

You can do this from the Photos app: File -> Import then select whichever ones you want. It's handy if you always save them to the same folder(maybe Downloads or a handy custom folder on your desktop).

In regards to why some of them saved but others didn't, I'm not even sure why some of them did save in the first place.